# Is an 'angle of slope' really the same on Earth and Moon?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I know (and it's easy to proof the formula), that the maximum angle at which an object will stay static on a slope being at an $\alpha$ angle to the ground is

$$\tan \alpha = \mu$$
where $\mu$ is the static COF (coefficient of friction).

[image]
<sub>(source: [sciencehq.com](https://www.sciencehq.com/wp-content/uploads/Angle-of-repose-300x240.jpg))</sub>

<sub>(http://www.sciencehq.com/wp-content/uploads/Angle-of-repose-300x240.jpg)</sub>

So it does not depend on an object's mass and a planet's gravitational constant.

But in a science-fiction book of Stanislaw Lem's there is a statement that implies an angle of slope is somehow different on the Moon that on Earth. It's not clear how and the author doesn't give any explanation. However, Lem usually takes care about a "science-corectness" of his texts. So it makes me wondering who/what is right: the formula or Lem? (or in other words: maybe in the 'real world' the angle really differs?)

Comment: What is the actual statement in the book you refer to? It's difficult to answer without knowing that.

Comment: @Chris The angle $\alpha$ on the Moon should be greater, according to the book.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. What exactly does the author say (not imply)? What explanation does he give?

Comment: He just says, that the angle is different. And it makes me wonder if this angle is really different or the author made a mistake.

Comment: If you have proved it, then why do you have doubts? If the real world was »different«, then your proof must be wrong. If it is not wrong then what you use in that proof  is wrong, or at least not representing the world correctly. But the friction model $f_k=\mu n$ is perfectly fine for low-force situations like yours. In the end, we all seem to agree on how it works, so unless you cite an accurate quote, people can only guess. My answer from the given details would be nothing more than: $$ $$ **Don't trust science from a sci-fi novelle**.

Comment: I don't trust them - but it makes me wonder. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**:

Lem is probably wrong. It's unlikely there is a relevant difference.

**Long answer**:

Forces other than Coulomb friction, such as van der Waals and electrostatic might help to keep the block in place. They are small compared to gravity on Earth, but in low gravity they could in principle play an increased role and lead to a higher angle.

Supposing that the [angle of repose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose) of granular materials can give us insight on the inclined plane problem, the former offers two advantages: i) due to the greater relevance of the granular problem, we can find enough results in the literature to attempt an answer, and ii) granular systems should average out some of the inconsistencies common to friction experiments.

It turns out that only Kleinhans et al. (2011) [Static and dynamic angles of repose in loose granular materials under reduced gravity](https://doi.org/10.1029/2011JE003865) claims to see a non-negligible effect:

> the static angle of repose increases about 5° with reduced gravity, whereas the dynamic angle decreases with about 10°

with most of the remaining research concluding that gravity has from small to negligible effects:

- Chen et al. (2015) [Numerical investigation on angle of repose and force network from granular pile in variable gravitational environments](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.powtec.2015.05.017)

  > Effect of gravity on the angle of repose of the pile is negligible.
- Atwood-Stone and McEwen (2013) [Avalanche slope angles in low-gravity environments from active Martian sand dunes](https://doi.org/10.1002/grl.50586)

  > [the dynamic angle of repose] does not significantly vary with decreasing gravity.
- Ji and Shen's (2009) [Two-Dimensional Simulation of the Angle of Repose for a Particle System with Electrostatic Charge under Lunar and Earth Gravity](https://doi.org/10.1061/(ASCE)0893-1321(2009)22:1(10))

  > the angle of repose shows little sensitivity to gravity.
- Ji and Shen's (2007) [Contrasting Terrestrial and Lunar Gravity: Angle of Repose and Incline Flows](https://doi.org/10.1061/40830(188)22)

  > The results show little sensitivity of the angle of repose to gravity.
- Nakashima et al. (2007) [Numerical Analysis of Sand Flow under Low Gravity Conditions](http://civil.kyushu-u.ac.jp/geotech/cd/pdf/475.pdf)

  > the effect of gravity condition on the angle of repose of sand was small
- Cherkasov et at. (1970) [Influence of gravity on the mechanical properties of soils](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01703618)

  > the gravity force does not influence the angle of repose of granular materials.